# Chef create directories recursively with owner

Tags: chef-infra

I need to create a tree of directories with owner "testuser".
But if I'm specify "/foo/bar/baz" only "baz" created under "testuser", "/foo" and "/foo/bar" own to "root" user.

```
directory /foo/bar/baz do
  owner 'testuser'
  group 'testuser'
  recursive true
  action :create
  mode '0755'
end
```

Based on this documentation https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html
we can use following structure and it's ok until I'm trying to use variables as directories.

```
%w[ /foo /foo/bar /foo/bar/baz ].each do |path|
  directory path do
    owner 'testuser'
    group 'testuser'
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```

If I specify variables in this list I've got directories with names "#{node[‘foo’]}" and so on.

```
%w[ #{node[‘foo’]} #{node[‘bar’]} #{node[‘baz’]} ].each do |path|
  directory path do
    owner 'testuser'
    group 'testuser'
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```

How to create a list of directories variables which will be expanded?

Answer (score 3):

### Avoid String Interpolation

You own solution relies on string interpolation of different items, which you later again split into its pieces.

You can avoid this e.g. in the following way, while I don't completely understand, where these attributes are coming from:

```rb
[node['foo'], node['bar'], node['baz']].each do |path|
  directory path do
    owner 'testuser'
    group 'testuser'
   mode '0755'
  end
end
```

### Avoid Declaring the Complete Path

A simpler way to create resources that recursively create `directory` resources for a complete path `foo/baz/bar`, you could use the following code, which splits the path into its pieces, without declaring the complete path in the manner of your question (`%w{foo foo/bar foo/bar/baz}`):

```rb
dir = "foo/bar/baz"
[].tap{|x| Pathname(dir).each_filename{|d| x << (x.empty? ? [d] : x.last + [d])}}.each do |dir|
  directory File.join(dir) do
    owner 'testuser'
    group 'testuser'
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```

Probably, there exists even a more elegant, shorter way to do it in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

if have default values in attributes like:

```
default["foo"]["logpath"] = "/var/log/apps"
```

then it be defined in recipe as to create directory :

```
directory node["foo"]["logpath"] do
  owner 'testuser'
  group 'testuser'
  recursive true
  mode '0755'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by myself.
If you want to interpolate variables use %W instead of %w

Comment: There is no reason to interpolate here. You're in ruby, so @StephenKing 's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need string interpolation. You're just working in straight ruby.

```
path = ''
path_ary = %w(foo bar baz) # or [node['foo'], node['bar'], node['baz'])
path_ary.each |path_element|
  path += "/#{path_element}"
  directory File.join(path) do
    owner 'testuser'
    group 'testuser'
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```